# Zum mit Genitiv

Tags: standard-german

Was ist der unterschied zwischen *um zu* und *zum + Genitiv*?

Zum Beispiel:

- Um einen Brief zu schreiben, brauche ich einen Bleistift.
- Zum Schreiben eines Briefs brauche ich einen Bleistift

Comment: There is no difference in the meaning, if that was the question.

Comment: Wo ist denn da ein Genitiv?

Comment: @DonHolgo Im zweiten Satz steht der Brief im Genitiv, im ersten nicht.

Comment: Freilich, aber wenn man das »zum + Genitiv« nennt, müsste doch eher »Schreiben« im Genitiv stehen, oder?

Answer (score 1):

Prinzipiell haben beide Sätze dieselbe Aussage, allerdings denke ich, dass die zweite Variante eher einen Fokus auf das "Schreiben" legt, während die erste Variante den Brief als Objekt des Fokus hervorhebt. Das ist jedoch eine sehr subtile Nuance, die ich persönlich so wahrnehme, in Alltagssprache wäre die erste Variante zu favorisieren, da sie weniger formal aber nicht umgangssprachlich wirkt.

Comment: Vielen Dank. Welcher satz ist im trend?

Comment: @MiladSaboonchi Der erste Satz.